# How can i access the cookie sent as a response from express in react js?

Tags: reactjs, express, cookies

I am using mern stack to make an application. For authentication i am using toke auth with passport authentication and for security reasons i am sending token in cookie. I have a login call which returns a cookie with response. The snippet is below:

```
    res.cookie("cookie_token", token, { maxAge: 84600 });
    res.send({
        status: "success"
    });
```

I can see the cookie in postman and even in browser in network(xhr request).

[image]

[image]

I am using axios for making call to the login api in react js.

```
 axios.get(myapiurl, {
        headers: {
          email: fields.email,
          password: fields.password,
          "access-control-allow-origin": "*"
        }
      })
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res);
        }).catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
```

Though i can't find a snippet to access the cookie in react js. How can i parse it? I can't see cookie in response of axios though? How can i access it.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this. Snippet from mdn.

```js
function getCookie(sKey) {
  if (!sKey) { return null; }
  return document.cookie.replace(new RegExp("(?:(?:^|.*;)\\s*" + sKey.replace(/[\-\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "\\s*\\=\\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$"), "$1") || null;
}

export function getLoginInfo() {
  const cookieToken = getCookie('cookie_token')
   console.log(cookieToken)
}
```